# Roots of $x^2 +2x +2$ Over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find  the roots of $x^2 +2x +2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

I need to prove somehow that the roots will be $(1 + i) , (1 - i)$

Any ideas how can I find those roots in a simple way?

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: Do you mean $-1+i$ and $-1-i$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the quadratic formula? Otherwise you can simply "guess" what the roots will be and then show indeed that they are roots.

Comment: It will be \sqrt -4 in the discrminant.

Comment: Note that $(2i)^2=(-2i)^2=-4$.

Comment: $\sqrt{-4}=2i{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, since $x^2+2x+2=(x+1)^2+1=0$

Then $(x+1)^2=-1$

so $x+1=\pm i$

thus $x=-1\pm i$

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the quadratic formula. When the root becomes negative, convert into complex numbers and you're done.
$x_{1,2} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2^2 - 4(1)(2)}}{2(1)}$
$x_{1,2} = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{-4}}{2}$
Convert $\sqrt{-4}$ into $2i$, then simplify by factoring out the 2. You'll be left with 
$1 + i$ and $1 - i$.
Or, if they already gave you the roots and you just need to show they are it, then consider polynomial long division, but that way takes more work in my opinion.

Comment: How do you convert $\sqrt (-4)$ into $2i$

Comment: $\sqrt{-4}=\sqrt(4)\sqrt(-1)=2i$

Comment: Thx @ellya . Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could "cheat," in a way. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know there can be at most two roots. Let's show that if we had those two roots then we would make that polynomial.
(x-1-i)(x-1+i)=x^2+2x+2 (based on wolfram alpha, and/or doing out the multiplication)
If you wanted to get the roots yourself, you could consider the quadratic formula. You'll have to deal with a possibly messy thing expression underneath the radical, but what's great about the complex numbers is that you can have a negative discriminant for the quadratic formula and not be sad.

Comment: $(x+1-i)(x+1+i)$, you mean.

Comment: I don't think I do. Isn't it that you do (x-r1)(x-r2) where r1 and r2 are the 2 roots?

Comment: Yes it is, but the roots are $-1\pm i$, not $1 \pm i$.

Comment: The roots given in the question are  (1+i),(1−i). I copy pasted them from above for this comment.